# Put SqlDataReader data into a DataTable while i process it

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, .net-4.0

I want to query a database and with the results, i want to process them. While im processing them, some of them will need to be inserted into another database. Since i cannot run another query with an open SqlDataReader (that i know of). I was thinking about putting the data from the SqlDataReader into a DataTable while i process it. Is there a built in way to do this or is there another solution that can accomplish the same idea?

Comment: Check this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cfa084cz(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: If its SqlServer have you thought of using SSIS, using DataTables and DataSets for manipulating stored data is a somewhat convoluted process compared to what can be achieved with SSIS.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx

Comment: @Lloyd I dont have that kind of access to the DB to setup SSIS, i only have a read only Sql id. Thanks for the idea though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(reader);
```

With the rest of the standard set-up and tear-down of SqlCommand objects, of course.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to use a DataAdapter to fill a datatable. Then process the data and update the database. Filling a dataset does not tie up the connection once the fill is complete.