# How to receive a SQL-Statement as a DataTable

Tags: c#, sql, datatable

I have the following code:

```
public static DataTable GetDataTable(string sConnStr, string sTable)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    SqlConnection sqlConn10 = new SqlConnection(sConnStr);
    sqlConn10.Open();
    SqlCommand sqlComm10 = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM " + sTable, sqlConn10);
    SqlDataReader myReader10 = sqlComm10.ExecuteReader();

    try
    {
        while (myReader10.Read())
        {
            // Code needed
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        myReader10.Close();
        sqlConn10.Close();
    }

    return dt;
}
```

The problem is, I don't know how to go on. All I want is to get a DataTable with the data from the SQL-Statement. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a data adapter:

```
public static DataTable GetDataTable(string sConnStr, string sTable)
{
    using (SqlConnection sqlConn10 = new SqlConnection(sConnStr))
    using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM EmployeeIDs", sqlConn10))
    {
        sqlConn10.Open();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(dt);
        return dt;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a `SqlDataReader`, use a `SqlDataAdapter`. A `DataReader` is for fast, forward-only operations, while the `DataAdapter` is geared towards set-based operations.

See MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.aspx

See http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqldataadapter for a simple example.

Answer (score 0):

```
DataAdapter.Fill(DataTable, mySqlQuery);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/497b1k4t.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Simply Do this:

```
SqlDataReader myReader10 = sqlComm10.ExecuteReader();
dt.Load(myReader10);
```

and `return dt;`

So your would be like this:

```
try
    {
        while (myReader10.Read())
         {
            dt.Load(myReader10);
         }
    }
    catch
    {
        myReader10.Close();
        sqlConn10.Close();
    }
return dt;
```

**The easiest way would be to use a DataAdapter to fill a datatable.**

```
public static DataTable GetDataTable(string sConnStr, string sTable)
{
    using (SqlConnection sqlConn10 = new SqlConnection(sConnStr))
    using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM " + sTable, sqlConn10))
    {
        sqlConn10.Open();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(dt);
        return dt;
    }
}
```

*// you should use best practices, use the using statement to dispose connection and other objects after completion of work.*

```
public static DataTable GetDataTable(string sConnStr, string sTable)
{    
   DataTable dt = new DataTable();
   try
   {
       using (SqlConnection sqlConn10 = new SqlConnection(sConnStr))
       using (SqlCommand sqlComm10 = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM " + sTable, sqlConn10))
       {
           sqlConn10.Open();
           using (SqlDataReader myReader10 = sqlComm10.ExecuteReader())
           {                     
               dt.Load(myReader10);
           }
       }
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
   }
   return dt;
}
```

Ref: [Put SqlDataReader data into a DataTable while i process it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9534718/put-sqldatareader-data-into-a-datatable-while-i-process-it)