# How to apply a SQL statement on one or more DataTable's?

Tags: sql, .net, linq, datatable, blueprism

### Question

Please help me writing a C# or vb.net routine that will accept

- a `DataTable`
- a SQL query as a `string`

and create

- a `DataTable` with the result of the query applied to the in put DataTable

To my knowledge, the tool to run SQL in .net is `linq`, but this does not lead me to a sollution.

In VB.net terms: How do I implement a function like this

```
Public Function SelectFromDataTable(Sql As String, T1 As DataTable) As DataTable
        // Apply Sql to T1
    End Function
```

*(or even better, like this)*

```
Public Function SelectFromDataTable(Sql As String, T1 As DataTable, Optional T2 As DataTable) As DataTable
        // Apply Sql to T1 and T2
    End Function
```

### What I tried so far

For some reason, I thought linq could be the solution, but that is no requirement.

#### Trial 1

if I look for the combination of linq and DataTable's I get that typicle syntax in which you write sql-like code inline in your .net code, as on. [Queries in LINQ to DataSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/queries-in-linq-to-dataset)

I want the query to be defined outside my routine,so **can you also create such queries from a SQL string**?

#### Trial 2

Looking for the combination of linq and SQL, I get examples using a `SqlDataAdapter`, but they need a `SqlConnection`, which apparently must point to a database, as in [How to receive a SQL-Statement as a DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10547638/how-to-receive-a-sql-statement-as-a-datatable)

However, for me, not only the destination, but also the source should be a DataTable, so **can you also create a `SqlConnection` to DataTables**?

### Context

If you are curious where my question comes from:

BluePrism is a graphic Robotic Process Automation (RPA) tool. It has one container object, called a `collection`, which is under the hood a .net `DataTable` and gives verry little support to manipulate these.

Fortunately, one can create so called "business objects" in .net and implements "Action" that receive and return variables. *(This is meant to manipulate other applications, but can also be used to manipulate data.)*

We already have such an object, which we called `Collection Manipulation`. One of the actions, `Filter Collection`, is implemented as

```
Dim NewRow As DataRow

Collection_Out = Collection_In.Clone

For Each parentRow As DataRow In Collection_In.Select(Select_Condition)
    NewRow = Collection_Out.NewRow
    For Each c As DataColumn In NewRow.Table.Columns
        NewRow(c.ColumnName) = parentRow(c.ColumnName)
    Next
    Collection_Out.Rows.Add(NewRow)
Next

NewRow = Nothing
Collection_In = Nothing
```

I would like to implement a general purpose Action, to runs queries against my collection like

```
select category, sum(unit_price * units) as total_price 
from invoice 
group by category;

select article, order.units - delivery.units as units_missing 
from order, delivery 
where order.article = delivery.article;
```

Comment: Can you use the `DataTable.Slect` method to filter out rows with a string? What type of queries do you need?

Comment: Thanks, I edited the __Context__ section of the question for you.

Comment: Does `linq` allow to store/view DataTables "as data base tables" and query them, even if you have no real data base?

Comment: can you directly use OLEDB methods on your data source or paste your collections into excel run the SQL query?

Comment: My datasource are `DataTable`s. Can I use OLEDB without a database?

Comment: @DirkHorsten As long as you are getting data from either excel or SQL into collection, you can directly get the data which you're willing to by querying join on SQL or excel (Considering excel as database). You can use either `Data - OLEDB` or `Data - SQL Server` VBO from Blue prism objects.

Comment: __1)__ "Data from SQL": do you mean from MS SQL server? I have no database. "Data from Excel" __2)__ Storing data into Excel and extracting it again can give conversion problems.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correct, you want a SQL syntax like multi-purpose select for data tables.

Based on the info found here: https://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheWeeklySourceCode48DynamicQueryableMakesCustomLINQExpressionsEasier.aspx, I wrote the following example further down. You can expand it as you see fit.

*TL;DR Add the System.Linq.Dynamic NuGet package so you can use strings for where clauses amongst others.*

BTW: Writing a query string parser, to parse for instance "select category, sum(unit_price * units) as total_price from invoice group by category;" is entirely possible, but IMHO you will spend a lot of time to gain little.

```
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Dynamic;

namespace Foo {
    public class Bar {
        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="from"></param>
        /// <param name="where"></param>
        /// <param name="skipRows"></param>
        /// <param name="takeRows"></param>
        /// <param name="orderBy">Needed for range selections (skipRows, takeRows) </param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public DataTable GeneralPurposeSelect(DataTable from, string where = null, int? skipRows = null, int? takeRows = null, string orderBy = "Id") {
            var fromQryAble = from.AsEnumerable().AsQueryable();

            IQueryable<DataRow> toQryAble = null;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(where)) {
                toQryAble = fromQryAble.Where(where);
            }
            if (takeRows != null) {
                if (skipRows == null) {
                    skipRows = 0;
                }
            }
            if (skipRows != 0) {
                if (takeRows == null) {
                    takeRows = int.MaxValue;
                }
            }
            if (takeRows != null) {
                if (skipRows == null) {
                    skipRows = 0;
                }
                toQryAble = toQryAble == null ?
                    fromQryAble.OrderBy(orderBy).Skip(skipRows.Value).Take(takeRows.Value) :
                    toQryAble.OrderBy(orderBy).Skip(skipRows.Value).Take(takeRows.Value);
            }

            return toQryAble == null ? from : toQryAble.CopyToDataTable();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for proposing the `IQueryable` interface, which apparently has a `GroupBy` method : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16522645/linq-groupby-sum-and-count/16523370. Though very usefull, it does not enable me to develop the general purpose function/action I hope to create. Looking forward to other answers.